# Delta timimg canvas getting trampled while trying to draw heart beat

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I'm very new to canvas and delta time updates so excuse my ignorance. I'm attempting to re-create a heart rate monitor (screenshot shown in jsfiddle, ideal final rendering to match https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ew6Jp74vaN4)

I can't work out why it seems to act so sporadically, especially when resizing the browser or doing other actions (I thought the idea behind delta timing was that it eliminates lag)

http://jsfiddle.net/alexcroox/CjCkV/

I'm using dt to work out when I need to move to the next point

```
var distance = Math.sqrt(
    (nextPosition.x-lastPosition.x)*(nextPosition.x-lastPosition.x) +
    (nextPosition.y-lastPosition.y)*(nextPosition.y-lastPosition.y)
);

var duration = distance/this.speed;
var t = this.totalTime/duration;
var x = (1.0 - t)*lastPosition.x + t*nextPosition.x;
var y = (1.0 - t)*lastPosition.y + t*nextPosition.y;
```

I did have a smoother version using just a counter and sin, but I was told it wouldn't be as smooth or flexible (I eventually want to fade out the "tail")

http://jsfiddle.net/alexcroox/AZ9zC/

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/CjCkV/14/

Comment: Also, `requestAnimationFrame` (and `setTimeout`) will skip frames when other processes take precedence. Instead of having the current position of the be based on the time difference, you can instead use a static time so that no points are ever skipped, or you could instead draw dots instead of lines: http://jsfiddle.net/CjCkV/15/

Comment: very nice thank you! The second demo certainly seems more stable, it does seem to skip points now and again though?

Comment: you can change total time like this `this.totalTime += 1/60;` and it will never miss a point.

Comment: Also, you probably shouldn't be defining the x portion of your coordinates. The heart monitor is based on time (the x axis), and magnitude (the y axis). This is a more accurate representation (though the code is a bit sloppy) http://jsfiddle.net/CjCkV/18/

Comment: wow that's really nice. Seems smooth as butter without any hickups! I'll just add the clearing of the burn trail and it will be very nice. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified the code a bit below. Here's the demo (with messy code) http://jsfiddle.net/CjCkV/19/

```
Game.prototype.renderBeat = function()
{
    // Get our current/target positions
    var position = this.points[this.nextPoint];
    var lastPosition = this.points[this.currentPoint] || position;

    var x = 0;
    var y = position.y;

    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.moveTo(x+1, lastPosition.y);
    this.context.lineTo(x, position.y);
    this.context.closePath();

    this.context.stroke();

    if (this.points[this.currentPoint]){        
         this.nextPoint = this.currentPoint;
    }

    // slowly fade out trail
    this.context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,.01)";
    this.context.fillRect(-this.translated, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    // this allows us to only care about the amplitude of the wave. 
    this.context.translate(1,0);
    this.translated += 1;

    this.currentPoint++;

    // if we've reached the last point in our array, loop around
    if(this.currentPoint > this.points.length)
    {   
        // random death (this randomly unsets any point except the first, slowing eliminating the "pulse"
        this.points[Math.floor(Math.random()*(this.points.length-2)+1)] = undefined;

        this.currentPoint = 0;
        this.nextPoint = 0;

        if (this.translated > this.canvas.width){
            this.context.translate(-this.translated, 0);
            this.translated = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Is the fading background (rectangle) used to achieve the fading tail? Only it will need to be completely transparent due to the pattern of the background it will sit on.

Comment: Yeah. You can go with a different method to do this. This is the easiest way to do it, but it will leave some remnants of the trail.